# ExtJs 5: Loading Mask in GridView

Tags: javascript, extjs, anonymous-function

In my ExtJs 5 application is a floating window, with a Grid within. The Gird has a hidden column, where i display an user-image. To avoid useless traffic, the images are only fetch by an additional store, when the user set the column visible. 
The code to Load the images is in the "beforerender" Event and when the loading is complete, the grid will be refreshed.

Because the loading can take a few seconds, i want to use the Mask to overlay the component.
But wen i want to add the mask, the following error occure:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'component' of null Renderable.js?_dc=1414507483010:938
```

I think the problem is cause by the event or the anonymous function.

```
listeners: {
    beforerender: function (column, metaData) {
        var store = Ext.getStore('MemberImagesStore');

        var grid = this.up('grid');
        var view = grid.getView();
        view.setMasked(true);
        store.loadMemberImages({
            scope: grid,
            callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                if (!success) {
                    return;
                }

                var view = this.getView();
                view.refresh();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I already tried different function parameter on different Components. But nothing worked for me. 
Anyone can show me an workaround to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `grid.mask('Loading...')` and, of course, `grid.unmask()`, when done.

Comment: This didn't worked in my case. Got the Error `[W] XTemplate evaluation exception: Cannot read property 'mask' of undefined` I think this error occur, because the property `protoEl` of the grid is null.

Comment: Then `grid` variable does not point to the grid instance. Depending on the scope, it can be `this` variable. Or the grid is not rendered yet.

Comment: The grid is already rendered, because the `beforrender` is assigned to a grid column and its hidden by default. Also i check with `conslole.log` the `grid` is the correct object.